# wait statement in C-component?

Tags: c, wait

Is there a wait statement in c-component? for example, wait for 0.5 second before continuing the process?

thanks!

Comment: what operating system are you programming for?

Comment: What do you mean by C-component?

Answer (score 7):

In POSIX there is

```
usleep(500);
```

and

```
nanosleep(...);
```

have a look at the manual of `usleep(3)` and `nanosleep(2)`. **EDIT**: `nanosleep` seems now to be the way to go, `usleep` is even deprecated in `POSIX.2008` according to its manpage!

Answer (score 7):

To summarize and correct a minor problem in Johannes Weiss' post (non-German keyboard, sorry):

In old-school POSIX, you could use the usleep() function, which accepts the number of microseconds to sleep as an unsigned integer argument. Thus, to sleep for half a second, you'd call:

```
#include <unistd.h>
usleep(500000); /* Five hundred thousand microseconds is half a second. */
```

For newer POSIX-style programs (my Gentoo Linux box' man pages says it's POSIX.1-2001), you'd use nanosleep(), which requires a pointer to a structure holding the period to sleep. Sleeping for half a second would look like this:

```
#include <time.h>
struct timespec t;
t.tv_sec = 0;
t.tv_nsec = 500000000; /* Five hundred million nanoseconds is half a second. */
nanosleep(&t, NULL); /* Ignore remainder. */
```

The second argument to nanosleep() is called "rem", and receives the remainder of the time, if the sleep is somehow interrupted. I left it at NULL for simplicity, here. You could do a loop until rem is (close enough to) zero, to make sure you really get your sleep, regardless of any interruptions.

Answer (score 3):

For Windows there is this function available in the API

```
Sleep(500);
```

Have a look at its [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686298%28VS.85%29.aspx) page. It sleeps for the specified amount of milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

sleep is also available in POSIX, the difference is that argument specifies the number of **Seconds** instead of Milliseconds the process should sleep.

Comment: Note that using sleep() may not work as expected if you also use alarm().